# Verificar nombre de un campo varchar y concatenarle un int en caso de que ya exista

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy reprogramando un calendario para guardar tareas a realizar y necesito un stored procedure que me permita verificar si existe el nombre de la tarea en la columna 'subject' de mi tabla Appointments,
si existe debe modificar el nombre agregandole al final "_" seguido un número comenzando en 1.
Sería algo así:

> *subject*
>    170811
>     170811_1
>   170811_2
>       ...
>      170811_n
>   170812
>   170812_1
>   170812_2
>   ...

tengo el siguiente código:

> Mi tabla Appointments:
>    UniqueID PK, int
>    Type int,
>   StartDate datetime,
>   EndDate datetime,
>    AllDay bit,
>   Location nvarchar(50),
>   Description nvarchar(max),
>   Status int,
>   Label int,
>   ResourceID int,
>   ResourcesIDs nvarchar(max),
>   ReminderInfo nvarchar(max)

y el stored procedure:

```
Create Proc sp_VerifNombreTarea
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_VerificarNombreTarea] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pNombreTarea varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @var int = 0
declare @pUniqueID int
declare @pType int
declare @pStartDate smalldatetime
declare @pEndDate smalldatetime
declare @pAllDay bit
declare @pLocation nvarchar(max)
declare @pStatus int
declare @pLabel int
declare @pResourceID int
declare @pResourceIDs nvarchar(max)
declare @pReminderInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pRecurrenceInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pTimeZoneId nvarchar(max)
declare @pCustomField1 nvarchar(max)
declare @Cant int
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    set @Cant = (select count(subject) from Appointments)
    if @Cant > 0
    begin
    set @pNombreTarea = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar)
    end

    insert into Appointments(Type ,StartDate, EndDate, AllDay, Location, Status, Label, ResourceID, ResourceIDs, 
                            ReminderInfo, RecurrenceInfo, TimeZoneId, CustomField1, subject)
            values(@pType, @pStartDate, @pEndDate, @pAllDay, @pLocation, @pStatus, @pLabel, @pResourceID, 
                    @pResourceIDs, @pReminderInfo, @pRecurrenceInfo, @pTimeZoneId, @pCustomField1, @pNombreTarea)

END
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto obtengo el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde debería mostrarme el nombre de la tarea como lo describí al principio.

### Actualización:

Ahora tengo este código con la ayuda de @Lamak:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_VerificarNombreTarea] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pNombreTarea varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @var int = 0
declare @pUniqueID int
declare @pType int
declare @pStartDate smalldatetime
declare @pEndDate smalldatetime
declare @pAllDay bit
declare @pLocation nvarchar(max)
declare @pStatus int
declare @pLabel int
declare @pResourceID int
declare @pResourceIDs nvarchar(max)
declare @pReminderInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pRecurrenceInfo nvarchar(max)
declare @pTimeZoneId nvarchar(max)
declare @pCustomField1 nvarchar(max)
declare @Cant int

SET NOCOUNT ON;
select @cant = case
                  when subject LIKE '%_%' then right(subject,len(subject)-CHARINDEX('_',subject)) + 1
                  else 1
               end
    from Appointments ;

    set @cant = isnull(@cant,0);

    if @Cant > 0
        begin
            update Appointments
            set subject = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar(max))
            where case 
             when subject LIKE '%_%' THEN left(subject, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', subject)-1, -1), LEN(subject))) 
             else subject 
          end = @pNombreTarea 

        end
END
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente resultado al haber creado 3 tareas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso suma 1 al último número del nombre y lo concatena al nombre anterior y mientras creo nuevas tareas repite nuevamnet el nombre, mientras que en la tarea nueva creada me ingresa el nombre que debería tener la tarea anterior. El resultado deseado es:  170811_1, 170811_2.

Comment: El nombre que toma el campo proviene de la fecha en que es creada la tarea en formato 'yyMMdd'. Agregué tres tareas el 11/08/2017 y una para el 12/08/2017.

Comment: Como es que llamas a este SP? y seguro no es insert, si no, no insertaria valores nulos. podrias mostrar la tabla original antes de los cambios?

Comment: Lo llamo al guardar la tarea que quiero crear. Me surge la confusión de hacer un insert o update al tener que insertar un nuevo registro en la tabla, donde si el campo 'subject' ya tiene un nombre existente, primero debe modificarlo y luego sí insertar el registro. ¿A que te referis con que muestre la tabla original?

Comment: pense que estabas transformando una tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Un par de comentarios. En primer lugar, no sé cómo con este código puedes estar insertando valores repetidos para la columna `subject`, no pareciera ser posible.

En segundo lugar, la línea donde chequeas si es único está mala, ya que revisas si la tabla completa tiene más de una fila o no, lo que claramente no es lo que quieres. Debería ser:

```
set @Cant = (select count(*) 
             from Appointments 
             where case 
                      when subject LIKE '%_%' then left(subject,CHARINDEX('_',subject)-1))
                      else subject
                   end = @pNombreTarea)
```

Por último, siempre que uses `varchar` o `nvarchar` debes asignarle un largo explícitamente:

```
set @pNombreTarea = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar(5))
```

ACUTALIZACIÓN:

Ok, lo que quieres hacer es bastante más complejo de lo que entendí inicialmente.
Debes cambiar el código de tu sp por lo siguiente (y tomar en cuenta que esto va a funcionar si la tabla ya cumple las condiciones de nombre de `subject` que describiste):

```
select @cant = case
                  when subject LIKE '%_%' then right(subject,len(subject)-CHARINDEX('_',subject)) + 1
                  else 1
               end
from Appointments ;

set @cant = isnull(@cant,0);

if @Cant > 0
begin
    update Appointments
    set subject = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar(5))
    where case 
             when subject LIKE '%_%' THEN left(subject,CHARINDEX('_',subject)-1))
             else subject
          end = @pNombreTarea 

end
else 
begin
    insert into Appointments(Type ,StartDate, EndDate, AllDay, Location, Status, Label, ResourceID, ResourceIDs, 
                            ReminderInfo, RecurrenceInfo, TimeZoneId, CustomField1, subject)
            values(@pType, @pStartDate, @pEndDate, @pAllDay, @pLocation, @pStatus, @pLabel, @pResourceID, 
                    @pResourceIDs, @pReminderInfo, @pRecurrenceInfo, @pTimeZoneId, @pCustomField1, @pNombreTarea)
end
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ahora con la corrección anterior en vez de modificar el nombre de la nueva tarea, lo ingresa en una nueva fila con el resto de los campos en NULL pero a partir del número 2 y no desde el 1. En esta nueva correccion no estaría entendiendo el código "end = @pNombreTarea" y ¿al case le falta la expresion a evaluar que en este caso sería subject?

Comment: Entonces definitivamente no entendí correctamente lo que quieres hacer. Es decir que ejecutas el procedimiento con todos esos valores, y si el subject ya existe lo único que hay que hacer es cambiarle el nombre?

Comment: Exactamente! Si el subject ya tiene ese nombre solo debe agregarle el '_' + el número: 170811
170811_1
170811_2

Comment: @PabloMatias actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Me da una excepción de parámetro de longitud no válido, le modifiqué el largo del varchar en "set subject = @pNombreTarea + '_' + CAST(@Cant as varchar(max))" pero siguen con el mismo error, estoy buscando como solucionarlo

Comment: @PabloMatias prueba ahora

Comment: Sigue lanzando el mismo error

Comment: hice unos ajustes a tu código y ahora obtengo un resultado parecido pero no es lo que busco

Comment: @PabloMatias sorry, es demasiado abierto tu comentario como para saber qué hacer a respecto